# enum, declaration outside of namespace and namespace causes "call of overloaded (...) is ambiguous"

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

Take the following:

`foo.h`

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <stdint.h>

enum directions {
    NORTH,
    EAST,
    SOUTH,
    WEST
};

bool foo_a(uint16_t a);
bool foo_b(enum directions a);

#endif //FOO_H
```

`foo.cpp`

```
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>

namespace test {
    bool foo_a(uint16_t a) {
        return a < 22;
    }

    bool foo_b(enum directions a) {
        return a < WEST;
    }

    bool foo(void) {
        return foo_a(16) || foo_b(NORTH);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << test::foo();
    return 0;
}
```

If we attempt to compile this, we get errors:

```
g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function ‘bool test::foo()’:
foo.cpp:17:40: error: call of overloaded ‘foo_b(directions)’ is ambiguous
   15 |         return foo_a(16) || foo_b(NORTH);
      |                                        ^
foo.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: ‘bool test::foo_b(directions)’
   10 |     bool foo_b(enum directions a) {
      |          ^~~~~
In file included from foo.cpp:2:
foo.h:14:6: note: candidate: ‘bool foo_b(directions)’
   14 | bool foo_b(enum directions a);
      |
```

So the compiler complains about an overloaded `foo_b`, but not about an overloaded `foo_a`. Why does it complain about `foo_b` at all? Why does it not just select the one in this namespace? And why is the `enum` treated different from the `uint16_t` (there are no errors about `foo_a`)?

Comment: Most likely [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) is being applied to the enum function but since `uint16_t` most likely maps to a built in type, no ADL happens for it.

Comment: @Eljay I know how to solve it, it is the question why which puzzles me.

Comment: Ahh, okay.  What NathanOliver said.  `foo_b` is ambiguous due to ADL.  `foo_a` isn't ambiguous due to ADL, because ADL is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

@NathanOliver already explained the reason. I'll try to elaborate on this.

First, here is an example that demonstrates why the compiler might be confused:

```
#include <stdint.h>

enum directions {
    NORTH,
    EAST,
    SOUTH,
    WEST
};

bool foo_a(uint16_t a);
bool foo_b(enum directions a);

namespace test {

    bool foo_a(uint16_t a) {
        return a < 22;
    }

    bool foo_b(enum directions a) {
        return a < WEST;
    }

    bool foo(void) {
        return foo_a(16) || foo_b();
    }
}

bool foo_b(enum directions a) {
    return a != SOUTH;
}
```

In this example, it might be unclear for the compiler whether `foo` should call `test::foo_b` or `foo_b` that is outside of the namespace. The compiler goes over the file in order, so when the compiler analyzes the call to `foo_b` from `foo`, it has no way of knowing whether there is or isn't a definition for `foo_b` outside the scope of `namespace test`.

Yet, the compiler had no problem with `foo_a`. That is because if the compiler has a few options, it will prefer the option that is declared in the most inner scope, in this case: `test::foo_a`.

But, the set of namespaces and classes that the compiler searches first for the function is affected by other things as well, e.g. the types of parameters that are passed to the function. According to [this manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl):

> 4. For arguments of enumeration type, the innermost enclosing namespace
>    of the declaration of the enumeration type is defined is added to the
>    set. If the enumeration type is a member of a class, that class is
>    added to the set.

So, due to `foo` calling `foo_b` with a parameter `NORTH` of type `enum direction`, the scope where `enum direction` is defined becomes just as "important" to the compiler as the inner namespace `test` (it is added to the "associated set of namespaces and classes"), they become equally important, and hence the compiler becomes confused between the two `foo_b` functions and can't decide which to use.

And that is why, in the following two examples below, the compiler has no problem. In the first example, the `NORTH` that `foo` passes to `foo_b` is of type `enum test::direction`, so the outer scope is not added to the compiler's "associated set of namespaces and classes". In the second example, `foo` calls `foo_b` without explicitly passing a parameter, hence again the outer scope is not added.

Example 1:

```
#include <stdint.h>

enum directions {
    NORTH,
    EAST,
    SOUTH,
    WEST
};

bool foo_a(uint16_t a);
bool foo_b(enum directions a);

namespace test {

    enum directions {
        NORTH,
        EAST,
        SOUTH,
        WEST
    };

    bool foo_a(uint16_t a) {
        return a < 22;
    }

    bool foo_b(enum directions a) {
        return a < WEST;
    }

    bool foo(void) {
        return foo_a(16) || foo_b(NORTH);
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
#include <stdint.h>

enum directions {
    NORTH,
    EAST,
    SOUTH,
    WEST
};

bool foo_a(uint16_t a);
bool foo_b(enum directions a = NORTH);

namespace test {

    bool foo_a(uint16_t a) {
        return a < 22;
    }

    bool foo_b(enum directions a = NORTH) {
        return a < WEST;
    }

    bool foo(void) {
        return foo_a(16) || foo_b();
    }
}
```